# Why bootstrapping tecnique is not being accurate for my non normal distribution?

Tags: r, bootstrapping

My code:

```
set.seed(1234)
population1 <- rpois(1000000, 0.6)
sample1 <- sample(population1, 30, replace=F)
mean(sample1)
sample_bs <-  replicate(200, mean(sample(sample1, 30, replace=T)))
mean(sample_bs)
gmodels::ci(sample_bs)
```

My results:

```
population mean: 0.6
sample mean: 0.4666

results from my boostrapping procedures:
Estimate    CI lower    CI upper  Std. Error 
0.467500000 0.450542365 0.484457635 0.008599396
```

So my question is: why the results from this procedures still far from the original population?

Comment: your first sample is too little ... so you are just bootstraping a sample with mean around 0.46 .. (An advice : dont give to your object the name of functions .. for the readibilty of your code)

Comment: May be, if you want to see what happens, could you try to change your "30" by, 50, and then 80, and then 100 .. and increase it and compare the results ..

Answer (score 0):

You are not sampling from your original population, you are sampling from your first sample! So the mean will be close to the mean of `sample1`, not `population1`.
Try this instead, and you will see how both results are close:

```
set.seed(1234)
population1 <- rpois(1000000, 0.6)
sample1 <- sample(population1, 30, replace=F)
mean(sample1)
sample_bs <-  replicate(200, mean(sample(population1, 30, replace=T)))
mean(sample_bs)
gmodels::ci(sample_bs)
```

Comment: But the central idea of bootstrapping is resample from your first and unique sample, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that the sample size is too small. We can make some educated guesses at the precision you can expect from a sample size of 30, and what sample size you'd need for a given expected precision.
We will assume a normal distribution, but for this to be reasonable, the distribution of what you want to measure needs to be reasonably normal. That is, the distribution of means needs to be reasonably normal, the distribution of a given sample needs not.
So…

```
set.seed(1234)
population1 <- rpois(1000000, 0.6)
sm30 <- scale(replicate(10000, mean(sample(population1, 30, rep=FALSE))))
s <- seq(-3, 3, by=0.01)
plot(s, dnorm(s, 0, 1), type="l", col="grey80", lwd=9)
lines(density(sm30), col=3, lwd=2)
```

[image]

That looks fairly normal (ish) to me. Some skew, but close enough for government work, as they say (CERN might demand better)

Assuming this is normal enough, we can continue estimating (this is [Stat101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps) stuff):

```
z <- qnorm(1-(0.05/2))
0.6 + z*c(-1, 1)*sqrt(0.6/30)
# 0.32281924 0.87718076
```

With a confidence level of 5% and a sample size of 30, we get some pretty wide confidence intervals (CI), as you experienced.
By rearranging the expression a bit, we can figure out what sample size we need for a given precision at a given confidence level. If we keep the 5% and say we want the CI to be at 0.6±0.1 we get:

```
(n <- ceiling((z*sqrt(0.6)/0.1)^2))
# 231
0.6 + z*c(-1, 1)*sqrt(0.6/n)
# 0.50011099 0.69988901
```

That's a bit more than 30.
While bootstrapping can help you estimating confidence intervals of non-normal distributions, it can't make up for missing information. The amount of information is inherent in the variance in your data, and the size of your sample.